# Как отследить отпускание кнопки kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

Как отследить отпускание кнопки kivy python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Событие on_release.

```
def call_func(self):
    ...

<Root>:

    Button:
        on_release:
            root.call_func()
```

Или в коде:

```
def call_func(self, instance):
    ....

Button(on_release=self.call_func)
```